# Installing CMUSphinx on remote Server/

Tags: centos, remote

I am remote user of super computer having `CentOS 6.5` I have to install

```
Sphinxbase. 
pocketsphinx. 
sphinxtrain.
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://jrmeyer.github.io/installation/2016/01/09/Installing-CMU-Sphinx-on-Ubuntu.html). It is for Ubuntu and works fine but I think it will work for CentOS as well. According to this tutorial we have to run three basic commands.

```
$ ./autogen, make and sudo make install
```

We are fine with first two commands. There is no problem with it. but problem is with **"sudo make install"**

As I mentioned, I am remote user so I don't have root user access. What is solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need these installed for all users of the system, get in contact with the system administrator of the machine and explain that you need to install these programs (and why you need them). The sysadmin will either [ignore you, or] install these herself, or, if she's careless, allow you limited `sudo` access.

If you only need these programs for yourself, then pass the `--prefix` flag to the `autogen.sh` script with a directory that you have write access to, e.g.

```
./autogen.sh --prefix="$HOME/sphinx"
```

When you later run `make install` (without `sudo`), the installation will be placed under `$HOME/sphinx` instead of in the default installation directories.

You will also have to replace all mentionings of `/usr/local` (which is the default installation directory) in the installation guide with `$HOME/sphinx`.